# Firebase notifications are not sending sometimes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have a firebase notification service which sends many times. For example, yesterday 56k notifications sended to multiple devices. However sometimes, can not receive notification, it pass this notification or 1 minute later sends. Is there a restriction to cause this, or am i missing a configuration ? It can send 2 notification in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> Keep in mind that the reporting of many of the statistics on this
>   page, are subject to delays up to 24 hours due to batching of
>   analytics data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery

Comment: I dont have problem with analytics, I just gave this example which is 56k for showing how much i use.

Comment: That's not about analytics. I'm also facing this problem. Sometimes it arrives, sometimes not.